# Listen from all the ports

Tags: sockets, networking, go

I'm writing a program which listen all the packets which come out from an interface. I've read the `net` godoc but all the possible methods I've found there require the `addr` in the form `host:port`. I would read all the packets which go out from one network interface. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this link will help.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Vk6Q9W0fpyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to all ports at once without listening on them separately, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean in the last sentence of your question.

I think what you're really after is a packet capture library, like [gopacket/pcap](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap).